# Задача: сколько на лугу пасется коров?

Tags: python

задача №3517 ,про коров в исполнители питон, помогите решить. Вот условие  :  Для данного числа n<100 закончите фразу “На лугу пасется...” одним из возможных продолжений: “n коров”, “n корова”, “n коровы”, правильно склоняя слово “корова”. Программа должна вывести введенное число n и одно из слов: korov, korova или korovy. Между числом и словом должен стоять ровно один пробел.

Answer (score 5):

Python 3
**1-й вариант:**

```
n = int(input())
if n >= 11 and n <= 14:
        print(n, 'korov')
else:
        temp = n % 10
        if temp == 0 or (temp >= 5 and temp <= 9):
                print(n, 'korov')
        if temp == 1:
                print(n, 'korova')
        if temp >=2 and temp <=4:
                print(n, 'korovy')
```

**2-й вариант:**

```
n = int(input())
if n in range(11, 15):
        print(n, 'korov')
else:
        temp = n % 10
        if temp in list(range(5,10))+[0]:
                print(n, 'korov')
        if temp == 1:
                print(n, 'korova')
        if temp in range(2,5):
                print(n, 'korovy')
```

Comment: @mctrane условия можно записать и по другому:

     temp in range(5,10)+[0]
     temp in range(2,5)

Только не забывать, что второй параметр range в диапазон уже не входит.

Comment: Да, это больше подчёркивает особенности Питона, поменял

Comment: А мне кажется, что предыдущий (традиционный) вариант был понятней (и не слишком длиннее). 

Т.е. в данной задаче list, range и проч. особенности Питона ничего не дают.

Comment: Выложил оба варината :) Не знаю как в других языках, но сравнивая с СИ++, PHP, Java. Это особенность: оператор in, сложение списков простым "+".

Comment: Хм, питоны разные бывают... А сначала удивился, когда увидел 

      list(range(5,10))+[0]

python3...

Comment: @avp уговорили

    n = int(input())
    if n >= 11 and n <= 14:
        print(n, 'korov')
    else:
        print (('korov','korova','korovy')[(0,1,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0)[n % 10]])

Comment: @alexlz, или как-то так


      const char *s = "";
      if (!(10 < n && n < 15)) {
        const char *sfx[] = {"","а","ы","ы","ы","","","","",""};
        s = sfx[n % 10];
      }
      printf ("%d коров%s\n", n, s);

Comment: фуууу, как жёстко ))

Answer (score 4):

Вариант решения используя только условную конструкцию if и арифметические\логические операции.

```
n = int(input())

if n % 10 == 1 and n != 11:
    print(n, 'korova')
elif 2 <= n % 10 <= 4 and n // 10 != 1:
    print(n, 'korovy')
else:
    print(n, 'korov')
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать [`gettext` модуль](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html), чтобы выбрать правильную форму множественного числа для текущего языка:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from gettext import translation

t = translation('messages', 'locale', fallback=True)
for n in [0, 1, 2, 5, 10, 11, 21, 22, 111]:
    print(t.ngettext("there is %d cow", "there are %d cows", n) % n)
```

Если запустить без перевода, то вывод:

```
$ python cows.py
there are 0 cows
there is 1 cow
there are 2 cows
there are 5 cows
there are 10 cows
there are 11 cows
there are 21 cows
there are 22 cows
there are 111 cows
```

Чтобы получить нужный вывод, необходимо добавить перевод, к примеру, с помощью `babel` модуля (`pip install babel`):

```
$ pybabel extract -o messages.pot .
extracting messages from cows.py
writing PO template file to messages.pot
$ pybabel init -i messages.pot -d locale -l ru
creating catalog locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po based on messages.pot
```

После добавления перевода в `message.po`:

```
msgstr[0] "На лугу пасётся %d корова"
msgstr[1] "На лугу пасётся %d коровы"
msgstr[2] "На лугу пасётся %d коров"
```

Чтобы сделать перевод доступным, необходимо собрать `messages.mo`:

```
$ pybabel compile -d locale
compiling catalog locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po to locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
```

Можно запустить с русским языком:

```
$ LANGUAGE=ru python cows.py
На лугу пасётся 0 коров
На лугу пасётся 1 корова
На лугу пасётся 2 коровы
На лугу пасётся 5 коров
На лугу пасётся 10 коров
На лугу пасётся 11 коров
На лугу пасётся 21 корова
На лугу пасётся 22 коровы
На лугу пасётся 111 коров
```

Это работает, потому что в `ru/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po` автоматически добавлено:

```
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=3; plural=(n%10==1 && n%100!=11 ? 0 : n%10>=2 && "
"n%10<=4 && (n%100<10 || n%100>=20) ? 1 : 2)\n"
```

---

При изменении текста, который нужно перевести в `cows.py`, следует обновить каталоги:

```
$ pybabel update -i messages.pot -d locale
updating catalog locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po based on messages.pot
```

И заново переводы собрать:

```
$ pybabel compile -d locale
compiling catalog locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po to locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
```

---

Чтобы добавить новый язык, к примеру французский:

```
$ pybabel init -i messages.pot -d locale -l fr
creating catalog locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po based on messages.pot
```

Добавить сам перевод для единственного и множественного числа:

```
msgstr[0] "Sur la prairie de pâture %d vache"
msgstr[1] "Sur la prairie de pâture %d vaches"
```

(для примера, фразы из Яндекс.Переводчика взяты)

Обновить `.mo` файлы:

```
$ pybabel compile -d locale
compiling catalog locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po to locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
compiling catalog locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po to locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
```

После этого можно запусить на французском:

```
$ LANGUAGE=fr python cows.py
Sur la prairie de pâture 0 vache
Sur la prairie de pâture 1 vache
Sur la prairie de pâture 2 vaches
Sur la prairie de pâture 5 vaches
Sur la prairie de pâture 10 vaches
Sur la prairie de pâture 11 vaches
Sur la prairie de pâture 21 vaches
Sur la prairie de pâture 22 vaches
Sur la prairie de pâture 111 vaches
```

Comment: На лугу пас**у**тся две коровы.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov: что в `message.po` писать это уже вопрос для сайта [Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/tour) :) Примеры, подтверждают ["пасутся" вариант](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9vpiubiXaU)

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
base = 'korov'
suffix = ''
if (n % 10 == 1) and n != 11:
    suffix = u'a'
elif n % 10 in ([2, 3, 4]) and n not in range(10, 21):
    suffix = u'y'
print(str(n), "{}{}".format(base, suffix))
```

Answer (score 0):

Для любителей "однострочников", вариант без ветвлений `if`:

```
print 'korov' + {n % 10 == 1 and n != 11: 'a', n % 10 in [2, 3, 4] and n not in range(10, 15): 'y'}.setdefault(1, '')

#44
#korovy
```