# Проблема с настройкой локализации приложения на Python 3.6.1

Tags: python-3.x, exec, перевод

Есть такой код:

```
def_done = 0

def get_user_lng():
    def_done = 0
    while def_done == 0:
        user_lng = input(user_lng_setup)
        user_lng = user_lng.replace(' ', '')
        user_lng = user_lng.lower()
        user_lng = re.sub(r'[0-9]*', '', user_lng)
        if user_lng == 'ru':
            exec(open('ru_ru.ini').read())
            print(selected_lang)
            def_done += 1
        elif user_lng == 'eng':
            exec(open('en_eng.ini').read())
            print(selected_lang)
            def_done += 1
        else:
            print(user_lng_setup_dntex)
            input()
            try:
                os.system('cls')
            except:
                os.system('clear')

exec(open('ru_ru.ini').read())

get_user_lng()
```

Эта функция была создана для настройки языка программы через exec(open(file).read())

Внизу перед телом программы есть строчка:

```
exec(open('ru_ru.ini').read())
```

Которая настраивает язык по умолчанию для корректного проведения функции get_user_lng. 
Проблема в том, что в ходе выполнения функция получает ввод ru либо en, и в зависимости от ввода должна применять .ini файлы содержащие перевод в формате:

```
variable = 'text translation'
```

Вообщем первый раз exec дефолтного языка происходит успешно, но потом когда ты выбираешь противоположный, он тупо не меняется.
Выбрал en, а тебе пишет: Русский язык успешно установлен. Вот так.
В чем проблема кода?

Comment: для переводов можно gettext модуль использовать, [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/735467/23044)

Comment: @jfs А иначе нельзя? gettext та еще запара, которую я хочу избежать. Вопрос в том, что не так в конкретно этом коде?

Comment: Решил тем, что вынес IF и ELSE вне функции, и добавил reutrn.