# Написание модуля. как запрашивать json только один раз?

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация

пишу модуль. как получать json не для каждого параметра отдельно. а на весь запрос целиком?

например я запрашиваю температуру и влажность. json запрашивается 2 раза чем расходует лимит обращений к api и тормозит работу

```
import urllib.request, json
import datetime

def time_converter(time):
    converted_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
        int(time)
    ).strftime('%H:%M')
    return converted_time

def geturl(city):
    #Moscow
    urll = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city +',ru&mode=json&units=metric&lang=ru&appid=*******'
    with urllib.request.urlopen(urll) as url:
        data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
        return data
        #print(data)

def temp(city):
    temp = str(geturl(city)['main']['temp'])+'\xb0' + 'C'+'\n'
    return temp

def pressure(city):
    pressure = str(geturl(city)['main']['pressure'])+' ммРтСт'+'\n'
    return pressure

def humidity(city):
    humidity = str(geturl(city)['main']['humidity'])+'%'+'\n'
    return humidity

def temp_min(city):
    temp_min = str(geturl(city)['main']['temp_min'])+'\xb0' + 'C'+'\n'
    return temp_min

def temp_max(city):
    temp_max = str(geturl(city)['main']['temp_max'])+'\xb0' + 'C'+'\n'
    return temp_max

def visibility(city):
    visibility = str(geturl(city)['visibility'])+'метров'+'\n'
    return visibility

def wind(city):
    wind= str(geturl(city)['wind']['speed'])+'м/с'+'\n'
    return wind

def weather(city):
    weather = str(geturl(city)['weather'][0]['description']) + '\n'
    return weather

def sunrise(city):
    sunrise = str(time_converter(geturl(city)['sys']['sunrise'])) + '\n'
    return sunrise

def sunset(city):
    sunset = str(time_converter(geturl(city)['sys']['sunset'])) + '\n'
    return sunset
```

Comment: Если у вас везде `geturl(city)`, то сделайте общий метод получения инфы. А из инфы вытаскиваете отдельно по всем данным: wind, weather, visibility и т.п. Тогда запрос будет один.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас везде `geturl(city)`, то сделайте общий метод получения инфы. А из инфы вытаскиваете отдельно по всем данным: `wind`, `weather`, `visibility` и т.п. Тогда запрос будет один.

Пример:

```
import urllib.request, json
import datetime

def get_data(city):
    urll = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + ',ru&mode=json&units=metric&lang=ru&appid=bd5e378503939ddaee76f12ad7a97608'
    with urllib.request.urlopen(urll) as url:
        data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
        return data

def temp(data):
    temp = str(data['main']['temp'])+'\xb0' + 'C'+'\n'
    return temp

def pressure(data):
    pressure = str(data['main']['pressure'])+' ммРтСт'+'\n'
    return pressure

def humidity(data):
    humidity = str(data['main']['humidity'])+'%'+'\n'
    return humidity
```

Использование:

```
data = get_data("Moscow")
print(temp(data))
print(pressure(data))
print(humidity(data))
```

---

Кроме того, эта задачка отлично решается через классы.

Проявите тут фантазию, пример:

```
class CityWeatherInfo:
    def __init__(self, city):
        self.city = city
        self.data = None

        self.sync_data()

    def sync_data(self):
        urll = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + self.city + ',ru&mode=json&units=metric&lang=ru&appid=bd5e378503939ddaee76f12ad7a97608'
        with urllib.request.urlopen(urll) as url:
            self.data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    
    def temp(self):
        temp = str(self.data['main']['temp'])+'\xb0' + 'C'+'\n'
        return temp
    
    def pressure(self):
        pressure = str(self.data['main']['pressure'])+' ммРтСт'+'\n'
        return pressure
    
    def humidity(self):
        humidity = str(self.data['main']['humidity'])+'%'+'\n'
        return humidity
```

Использование:

```
info = CityWeatherInfo("Moscow")
print(info.temp())
print(info.pressure())
print(info.humidity())
```

Comment: Есть смысл прописывать ещё раз вызов функции `sync_data` если вы ее в `__init__` и так вызываете?

Comment: Спс, сначала был вызов вне, потом решил добавить в конструктор, чтобы `self.data` не пустовал, вот и забыл удалить

Answer (score 1):

Можно отделить как данные собираются, от того как они отображаются. Интересные для приложения данные о погоде, можно в виде [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) представить:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Weather = namedtuple('Weather',
                     ['temp',
                      'pressure',
                      'humidity',
                      'temp_min',
                      'temp_max',
                      'visibility',
                      'wind',
                      'description',
                      'time'])
```

Чтобы загрузить данные о погоде с указанного сервиса:

```
import datetime as DT
import json
import os
from urllib.parse import quote
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

appname = "so-805781-weather-client"
__version__ = "0.1.1"
appid = os.environ['OPENWEATHERMAP_APPID']


@cache_for(minutes=10)
def get_weather_for(city):
    r = Request('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='
                + quote(city)
                + ',ru&mode=json&units=metric&lang=ru&APPID='
                + quote(appid),
                headers={'User-Agent': f'{appname}/{__version__}'})
    with urlopen(r) as response:
        data = json.loads(response.read().decode())
    return Weather(visibility=data['visibility'],
                   wind=data['wind']['speed'],
                   description=data['weather'][0]['description'],
                   time=DT.datetime.now(DT.timezone.utc).astimezone(),
                   **data['main'])
```

где `@cache_for(minutes=10)` кэширует результаты функции на 10 минут (см. в конце ответа). Пример:

```
print(get_weather_for('Moscow'))
```

Вывод:

```
Weather(temp=-2.5, pressure=1014, humidity=53, temp_min=-3, temp_max=-2, visibility=10000, wind=2, description='ясно', time=datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 28, 14, 3, 8, 96334, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 10800), 'MSK')))
```

Чтобы напечатать данные в желаемом формате, можно простую функцию использовать:

```
from textwrap import dedent

def display_weather(info):
    print(dedent("""\
    {temp} ℃
    {pressure} ммРтСт
    {humidity} %
    {temp_min} ℃
    {temp_max} ℃
    {visibility} метров
    {wind} м/с
    {description}
    {time:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}""".format_map(info._asdict())))
```

Пример:

```
display_weather(get_weather_for('Moscow'))
```

Результат:

```
-2.5 ℃
1014 ммРтСт
53 %
-3 ℃
-2 ℃
10000 метров
2 м/с
ясно
2018-03-28 14:03:08
```

При желании, можно поддержку нескольких языков добавить, [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/735467/23044).

---

Реализация `cache_for()` декоратора:

```
import functools
from werkzeug.contrib.cache import FileSystemCache  # $ pip install werkzeug

cache = FileSystemCache('.cachedir')

def cache_for(**timedelta_kwargs):
    timeout = DT.timedelta(**timedelta_kwargs).total_seconds()

    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(arg):
            result = cache.get(key=arg)
            if not result:
                result = func(arg)
                cache.set(arg, result, timeout=timeout)
            return result
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```