# Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу с https://stepik.org/lesson/5047/step/6?unit=1086!

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Задача](https://stepik.org/lesson/5047/step/6?unit=1086):

> Напишите программу, считывающую с пользовательского ввода целое число
>   n (неотрицательное), выводящее это число в консоль вместе с правильным
>   образом изменённым словом "программист", для того, чтобы робот мог
>   нормально общаться с людьми, например: 1 программист, 2 программиста,
>   5 программистов.
>
> В комнате может быть очень много программистов. Проверьте, что ваша
>   программа правильно обработает все случаи, как минимум до 1000
>   человек.

У меня получился такой вот код, который я перепроверил сотню раз, но сайт выдаёт ошибку:

```
n = int(input())

if n % 10 == 0 or n // 10 == 1 or n // 10 == 11 or n % 10 == 5 or n % 10 == 6 or n % 10 == 7 or n % 10 == 8 or n % 10 == 9:
  print(n, "программистов")

elif n % 10 == 1 and n // 10 != 1 and n // 10 != 11:
  print(n, "программист")

elif n % 10 == 2 or n % 10 == 3 or n % 10 == 4:
  print(n, "программиста")
```

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос - ссылку перенесите в тело вопроса, Лучше суть задачи привести здесь (всю лирику не надо, достаточно двух абзацев начиная с "Напишите"). А код обязательно отформатируйте и примените тэг "код" (выделить код и нажать значок `{}`)- иначе его невозможно прочитать

Comment: И **обязательно** нужно вставлять в вопрос текст ошибки!

Comment: Во-первых, ``n // 10 != 11`` - это лишнее и не имеет смысла (как и ``n // 10 == 11``). Остаток от деления на 10 никогда не будет 11. Во-вторых, в это строчке стоит ``and``, хотя наверняка нужно ``or``.

Comment: В третьих, делать ``n % 10 == 1`` и ``n // 10 != 1`` в одном условии не имеет смысла ни через ``or`` - всегда будет True, ни через ``and`` - всегда будет False. Остаток от деления или равен 1 или не равен 1.

Comment: @Эникейщик, так `//` - это деление, а не остаток от деления.

Comment: @Qwertiy  Блин, глаз замылился! Пардон.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Задача: сколько на лугу пасется коров?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/307354/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Условие можно составить проще:

```
n = int(input())

mod10 = n % 10
mod100 = n % 100

if mod10 == 1 and mod100 != 11:
    end = ''
elif (1 < mod10 < 5) and not (11 < mod100 < 15):
    end = 'а'
else:
    end = 'ов'

print(f'{n} программист{end}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто заполните все варианты и вы красавчик! :D

```
dct = {
    0: '0 программистов', 1: '1 программист', 2: '2 программиста', 3: '3 программиста', 4: '4 программиста',
    5: '5 программистов', 6: '6 программистов', 7: '7 программистов', 8: '8 программистов', 9: '9 программистов',
    10: '10 программистов', 11: '11 программистов', 12: '12 программистов', 13: '13 программистов',
    14: '14 программистов', 15: '15 программистов', 16: '16 программистов', 17: '17 программистов',
    18: '18 программистов', 19: '19 программистов', 20: '20 программистов', 21: '21 программист',
    22: '22 программиста', 23: '23 программиста', 24: '24 программиста', 25: '25 программистов',
    26: '26 программистов', 27: '27 программистов', 28: '28 программистов', 29: '29 программистов',
    30: '30 программистов', 31: '31 программист', 32: '32 программиста', 33: '33 программиста',
    34: '34 программиста', 35: '35 программистов', 36: '36 программистов', 37: '37 программистов',
    38: '38 программистов', 39: '39 программистов', 40: '40 программистов', 41: '41 программист',
    42: '42 программиста', 43: '43 программиста', 44: '44 программиста', 45: '45 программистов',
    46: '46 программистов', 47: '47 программистов', 48: '48 программистов', 49: '49 программистов',
    50: '50 программистов', 51: '51 программист', 52: '52 программиста', 53: '53 программиста',
    54: '54 программиста', 55: '55 программистов', 56: '56 программистов', 57: '57 программистов',
    58: '58 программистов', 59: '59 программистов', 60: '60 программистов', 61: '61 программист',
    62: '62 программиста', 63: '63 программиста', 64: '64 программиста', 65: '65 программистов',
    66: '66 программистов', 67: '67 программистов', 68: '68 программистов', 69: '69 программистов',
    70: '70 программистов', 71: '71 программист', 72: '72 программиста', 73: '73 программиста',
    74: '74 программиста', 75: '75 программистов', 76: '76 программистов', 77: '77 программистов',
    78: '78 программистов', 79: '79 программистов', 80: '80 программистов', 81: '81 программист',
    82: '82 программиста', 83: '83 программиста', 84: '84 программиста', 85: '85 программистов',
    86: '86 программистов', 87: '87 программистов', 88: '88 программистов', 89: '89 программистов',
    90: '90 программистов', 91: '91 программист', 92: '92 программиста', 93: '93 программиста',
    94: '94 программиста', 95: '95 программистов', 96: '96 программистов', 97: '97 программистов',
    98: '98 программистов', 99: '99 программистов', 100: '100 программистов', 101: '101 программист',
    102: '102 программиста', 103: '103 программиста', 104: '104 программиста', 105: '105 программистов',
    106: '106 программистов', 107: '107 программистов', 108: '108 программистов', 109: '109 программистов',
    110: '110 программистов', 111: '111 программистов', 112: '112 программистов', 113: '113 программистов',
    114: '114 программистов', 115: '115 программистов', 116: '116 программистов', 117: '117 программистов',
    118: '118 программистов', 119: '119 программистов', 120: '120 программистов', 121: '121 программист',
    122: '122 программиста', 123: '123 программиста', 124: '124 программиста', 125: '125 программистов',
    126: '126 программистов', 127: '127 программистов', 128: '128 программистов', 129: '129 программистов',
    130: '130 программистов', 131: '131 программист', 132: '132 программиста', 133: '133 программиста',
    134: '134 программиста', 135: '135 программистов', 136: '136 программистов', 137: '137 программистов',
    138: '138 программистов', 139: '139 программистов', 140: '140 программистов', 141: '141 программист',
    142: '142 программиста', 143: '143 программиста', 144: '144 программиста', 145: '145 программистов',
    146: '146 программистов', 147: '147 программистов', 148: '148 программистов', 149: '149 программистов',
    150: '150 программистов', 151: '151 программист', 152: '152 программиста', 153: '153 программиста',
    154: '154 программиста', 155: '155 программистов', 156: '156 программистов', 157: '157 программистов',
    158: '158 программистов', 159: '159 программистов', 160: '160 программистов', 161: '161 программист',
    162: '162 программиста', 163: '163 программиста', 164: '164 программиста', 165: '165 программистов',
    166: '166 программистов', 167: '167 программистов', 168: '168 программистов', 169: '169 программистов',
    170: '170 программистов', 171: '171 программист', 172: '172 программиста', 173: '173 программиста',
    174: '174 программиста', 175: '175 программистов', 176: '176 программистов', 177: '177 программистов',
    178: '178 программистов', 179: '179 программистов', 180: '180 программистов', 181: '181 программист',
    182: '182 программиста', 183: '183 программиста', 184: '184 программиста', 185: '185 программистов',
    186: '186 программистов', 187: '187 программистов', 188: '188 программистов', 189: '189 программистов',
    190: '190 программистов', 191: '191 программист', 192: '192 программиста', 193: '193 программиста',
    194: '194 программиста', 195: '195 программистов', 196: '196 программистов', 197: '197 программистов',
    198: '198 программистов', 199: '199 программистов', 200: '200 программистов', 201: '201 программист',
    202: '202 программиста', 203: '203 программиста', 204: '204 программиста', 205: '205 программистов',
    206: '206 программистов', 207: '207 программистов', 208: '208 программистов', 209: '209 программистов',
    210: '210 программистов', 211: '211 программистов', 212: '212 программистов', 213: '213 программистов',
    214: '214 программистов', 215: '215 программистов', 216: '216 программистов', 217: '217 программистов',
    218: '218 программистов', 219: '219 программистов', 220: '220 программистов', 221: '221 программист',
    222: '222 программиста', 223: '223 программиста', 224: '224 программиста', 225: '225 программистов',
    226: '226 программистов', 227: '227 программистов', 228: '228 программистов', 229: '229 программистов',
    230: '230 программистов', 231: '231 программист', 232: '232 программиста', 233: '233 программиста',
    234: '234 программиста', 235: '235 программистов', 236: '236 программистов', 237: '237 программистов',
    238: '238 программистов', 239: '239 программистов', 240: '240 программистов', 241: '241 программист',
    242: '242 программиста', 243: '243 программиста', 244: '244 программиста', 245: '245 программистов',
    246: '246 программистов', 247: '247 программистов', 248: '248 программистов', 249: '249 программистов',
    250: '250 программистов', 251: '251 программист', 252: '252 программиста', 253: '253 программиста',
    254: '254 программиста', 255: '255 программистов', 256: '256 программистов', 257: '257 программистов',
    258: '258 программистов', 259: '259 программистов', 260: '260 программистов', 261: '261 программист',
    262: '262 программиста', 263: '263 программиста', 264: '264 программиста', 265: '265 программистов',
    266: '266 программистов', 267: '267 программистов', 268: '268 программистов', 269: '269 программистов',
    270: '270 программистов', 271: '271 программист', 272: '272 программиста', 273: '273 программиста',
    274: '274 программиста', 275: '275 программистов', 276: '276 программистов', 277: '277 программистов',
    278: '278 программистов', 279: '279 программистов', 280: '280 программистов', 281: '281 программист',
    282: '282 программиста', 283: '283 программиста', 284: '284 программиста', 285: '285 программистов',
    286: '286 программистов', 287: '287 программистов', 288: '288 программистов', 289: '289 программистов',
    290: '290 программистов', 291: '291 программист', 292: '292 программиста', 293: '293 программиста',
    294: '294 программиста', 295: '295 программистов', 296: '296 программистов', 297: '297 программистов',
    298: '298 программистов', 299: '299 программистов', 300: '300 программистов', 301: '301 программист',
    302: '302 программиста', 303: '303 программиста', 304: '304 программиста', 305: '305 программистов',
    306: '306 программистов', 307: '307 программистов', 308: '308 программистов', 309: '309 программистов',
    310: '310 программистов', 311: '311 программистов', 312: '312 программистов', 313: '313 программистов',
    314: '314 программистов', 315: '315 программистов', 316: '316 программистов', 317: '317 программистов',
    318: '318 программистов', 319: '319 программистов', 320: '320 программистов', 321: '321 программист',
    322: '322 программиста', 323: '323 программиста', 324: '324 программиста', 325: '325 программистов',
    326: '326 программистов', 327: '327 программистов', 328: '328 программистов', 329: '329 программистов',
    330: '330 программистов', 331: '331 программист', 332: '332 программиста', 333: '333 программиста',
    334: '334 программиста', 335: '335 программистов', 336: '336 программистов', 337: '337 программистов',
    338: '338 программистов', 339: '339 программистов', 340: '340 программистов', 341: '341 программист',
    342: '342 программиста', 343: '343 программиста', 344: '344 программиста', 345: '345 программистов',
    346: '346 программистов', 347: '347 программистов', 348: '348 программистов', 349: '349 программистов',
    350: '350 программистов', 351: '351 программист', 352: '352 программиста', 353: '353 программиста',
    354: '354 программиста', 355: '355 программистов', 356: '356 программистов', 357: '357 программистов',
    358: '358 программистов', 359: '359 программистов', 360: '360 программистов', 361: '361 программист',
    362: '362 программиста', 363: '363 программиста', 364: '364 программиста', 365: '365 программистов',
    366: '366 программистов', 367: '367 программистов', 368: '368 программистов', 369: '369 программистов',
    370: '370 программистов', 371: '371 программист', 372: '372 программиста', 373: '373 программиста',
    374: '374 программиста', 375: '375 программистов', 376: '376 программистов', 377: '377 программистов',
    378: '378 программистов', 379: '379 программистов', 380: '380 программистов', 381: '381 программист',
    382: '382 программиста', 383: '383 программиста', 384: '384 программиста', 385: '385 программистов',
    386: '386 программистов', 387: '387 программистов', 388: '388 программистов', 389: '389 программистов',
    390: '390 программистов', 391: '391 программист', 392: '392 программиста', 393: '393 программиста',
    394: '394 программиста', 395: '395 программистов', 396: '396 программистов', 397: '397 программистов',
    398: '398 программистов', 399: '399 программистов', 400: '400 программистов', 401: '401 программист',
    402: '402 программиста', 403: '403 программиста', 404: '404 программиста', 405: '405 программистов',
    406: '406 программистов', 407: '407 программистов', 408: '408 программистов', 409: '409 программистов',
    410: '410 программистов', 411: '411 программистов', 412: '412 программистов', 413: '413 программистов',
    414: '414 программистов', 415: '415 программистов', 416: '416 программистов', 417: '417 программистов',
    418: '418 программистов', 419: '419 программистов', 420: '420 программистов', 421: '421 программист',
    422: '422 программиста', 423: '423 программиста', 424: '424 программиста', 425: '425 программистов',
    426: '426 программистов', 427: '427 программистов', 428: '428 программистов', 429: '429 программистов',
    430: '430 программистов', 431: '431 программист', 432: '432 программиста', 433: '433 программиста',
    434: '434 программиста', 435: '435 программистов', 436: '436 программистов', 437: '437 программистов',
    438: '438 программистов', 439: '439 программистов', 440: '440 программистов', 441: '441 программист',
    442: '442 программиста', 443: '443 программиста', 444: '444 программиста', 445: '445 программистов',
    446: '446 программистов', 447: '447 программистов', 448: '448 программистов', 449: '449 программистов',
    450: '450 программистов', 451: '451 программист', 452: '452 программиста', 453: '453 программиста',
    454: '454 программиста', 455: '455 программистов', 456: '456 программистов', 457: '457 программистов',
    458: '458 программистов', 459: '459 программистов', 460: '460 программистов', 461: '461 программист',
    462: '462 программиста', 463: '463 программиста', 464: '464 программиста', 465: '465 программистов',
    466: '466 программистов', 467: '467 программистов', 468: '468 программистов', 469: '469 программистов',
    470: '470 программистов', 471: '471 программист', 472: '472 программиста', 473: '473 программиста',
    474: '474 программиста', 475: '475 программистов', 476: '476 программистов', 477: '477 программистов',
    478: '478 программистов', 479: '479 программистов', 480: '480 программистов', 481: '481 программист',
    482: '482 программиста', 483: '483 программиста', 484: '484 программиста', 485: '485 программистов',
    486: '486 программистов', 487: '487 программистов', 488: '488 программистов', 489: '489 программистов',
    490: '490 программистов', 491: '491 программист', 492: '492 программиста', 493: '493 программиста',
    494: '494 программиста', 495: '495 программистов', 496: '496 программистов', 497: '497 программистов',
    498: '498 программистов', 499: '499 программистов', 500: '500 программистов', 501: '501 программист',
    502: '502 программиста', 503: '503 программиста', 504: '504 программиста', 505: '505 программистов',
    506: '506 программистов', 507: '507 программистов', 508: '508 программистов', 509: '509 программистов',
    510: '510 программистов', 511: '511 программистов', 512: '512 программистов', 513: '513 программистов',
    514: '514 программистов', 515: '515 программистов', 516: '516 программистов', 517: '517 программистов',
    518: '518 программистов', 519: '519 программистов', 520: '520 программистов', 521: '521 программист',
    522: '522 программиста', 523: '523 программиста', 524: '524 программиста', 525: '525 программистов',
    526: '526 программистов', 527: '527 программистов', 528: '528 программистов', 529: '529 программистов',
    530: '530 программистов', 531: '531 программист', 532: '532 программиста', 533: '533 программиста',
    534: '534 программиста', 535: '535 программистов', 536: '536 программистов', 537: '537 программистов',
    538: '538 программистов', 539: '539 программистов', 540: '540 программистов', 541: '541 программист',
    542: '542 программиста', 543: '543 программиста', 544: '544 программиста', 545: '545 программистов',
    546: '546 программистов', 547: '547 программистов', 548: '548 программистов', 549: '549 программистов',
    550: '550 программистов', 551: '551 программист', 552: '552 программиста', 553: '553 программиста',
    554: '554 программиста', 555: '555 программистов', 556: '556 программистов', 557: '557 программистов',
    558: '558 программистов', 559: '559 программистов', 560: '560 программистов', 561: '561 программист',
    562: '562 программиста', 563: '563 программиста', 564: '564 программиста', 565: '565 программистов',
    566: '566 программистов', 567: '567 программистов', 568: '568 программистов', 569: '569 программистов',
    570: '570 программистов', 571: '571 программист', 572: '572 программиста', 573: '573 программиста',
    574: '574 программиста', 575: '575 программистов', 576: '576 программистов', 577: '577 программистов',
    578: '578 программистов', 579: '579 программистов', 580: '580 программистов', 581: '581 программист',
    582: '582 программиста', 583: '583 программиста', 584: '584 программиста', 585: '585 программистов',
    586: '586 программистов', 587: '587 программистов', 588: '588 программистов', 589: '589 программистов',
    590: '590 программистов', 591: '591 программист', 592: '592 программиста', 593: '593 программиста',
    594: '594 программиста', 595: '595 программистов', 596: '596 программистов', 597: '597 программистов',
    598: '598 программистов', 599: '599 программистов', 600: '600 программистов', 601: '601 программист',
    602: '602 программиста', 603: '603 программиста', 604: '604 программиста', 605: '605 программистов',
    606: '606 программистов', 607: '607 программистов', 608: '608 программистов', 609: '609 программистов',
    610: '610 программистов', 611: '611 программистов', 612: '612 программистов', 613: '613 программистов',
    614: '614 программистов', 615: '615 программистов', 616: '616 программистов', 617: '617 программистов',
    618: '618 программистов', 619: '619 программистов', 620: '620 программистов', 621: '621 программист',
    622: '622 программиста', 623: '623 программиста', 624: '624 программиста', 625: '625 программистов',
    626: '626 программистов', 627: '627 программистов', 628: '628 программистов', 629: '629 программистов',
    630: '630 программистов', 631: '631 программист', 632: '632 программиста', 633: '633 программиста',
    634: '634 программиста', 635: '635 программистов', 636: '636 программистов', 637: '637 программистов',
    638: '638 программистов', 639: '639 программистов', 640: '640 программистов', 641: '641 программист',
    642: '642 программиста', 643: '643 программиста', 644: '644 программиста', 645: '645 программистов',
    646: '646 программистов', 647: '647 программистов', 648: '648 программистов', 649: '649 программистов',
    650: '650 программистов', 651: '651 программист', 652: '652 программиста', 653: '653 программиста',
    654: '654 программиста', 655: '655 программистов', 656: '656 программистов', 657: '657 программистов',
    658: '658 программистов', 659: '659 программистов', 660: '660 программистов', 661: '661 программист',
    662: '662 программиста', 663: '663 программиста', 664: '664 программиста', 665: '665 программистов',
    666: '666 программистов', 667: '667 программистов', 668: '668 программистов', 669: '669 программистов',
    670: '670 программистов', 671: '671 программист', 672: '672 программиста', 673: '673 программиста',
    674: '674 программиста', 675: '675 программистов', 676: '676 программистов', 677: '677 программистов',
    678: '678 программистов', 679: '679 программистов', 680: '680 программистов', 681: '681 программист',
    682: '682 программиста', 683: '683 программиста', 684: '684 программиста', 685: '685 программистов',
    686: '686 программистов', 687: '687 программистов', 688: '688 программистов', 689: '689 программистов',
    690: '690 программистов', 691: '691 программист', 692: '692 программиста', 693: '693 программиста',
    694: '694 программиста', 695: '695 программистов', 696: '696 программистов', 697: '697 программистов',
    698: '698 программистов', 699: '699 программистов', 700: '700 программистов', 701: '701 программист',
    702: '702 программиста', 703: '703 программиста', 704: '704 программиста', 705: '705 программистов',
    706: '706 программистов', 707: '707 программистов', 708: '708 программистов', 709: '709 программистов',
    710: '710 программистов', 711: '711 программистов', 712: '712 программистов', 713: '713 программистов',
    714: '714 программистов', 715: '715 программистов', 716: '716 программистов', 717: '717 программистов',
    718: '718 программистов', 719: '719 программистов', 720: '720 программистов', 721: '721 программист',
    722: '722 программиста', 723: '723 программиста', 724: '724 программиста', 725: '725 программистов',
    726: '726 программистов', 727: '727 программистов', 728: '728 программистов', 729: '729 программистов',
    730: '730 программистов', 731: '731 программист', 732: '732 программиста', 733: '733 программиста',
    734: '734 программиста', 735: '735 программистов', 736: '736 программистов', 737: '737 программистов',
    738: '738 программистов', 739: '739 программистов', 740: '740 программистов', 741: '741 программист',
    742: '742 программиста', 743: '743 программиста', 744: '744 программиста', 745: '745 программистов',
    746: '746 программистов', 747: '747 программистов', 748: '748 программистов', 749: '749 программистов',
    750: '750 программистов', 751: '751 программист', 752: '752 программиста', 753: '753 программиста',
    754: '754 программиста', 755: '755 программистов', 756: '756 программистов', 757: '757 программистов',
    758: '758 программистов', 759: '759 программистов', 760: '760 программистов', 761: '761 программист',
    762: '762 программиста', 763: '763 программиста', 764: '764 программиста', 765: '765 программистов',
    766: '766 программистов', 767: '767 программистов', 768: '768 программистов', 769: '769 программистов',
    770: '770 программистов', 771: '771 программист', 772: '772 программиста', 773: '773 программиста',
    774: '774 программиста', 775: '775 программистов', 776: '776 программистов', 777: '777 программистов',
    778: '778 программистов', 779: '779 программистов', 780: '780 программистов', 781: '781 программист',
    782: '782 программиста', 783: '783 программиста', 784: '784 программиста', 785: '785 программистов',
    786: '786 программистов', 787: '787 программистов', 788: '788 программистов', 789: '789 программистов',
    790: '790 программистов', 791: '791 программист', 792: '792 программиста', 793: '793 программиста',
    794: '794 программиста', 795: '795 программистов', 796: '796 программистов', 797: '797 программистов',
    798: '798 программистов', 799: '799 программистов', 800: '800 программистов', 801: '801 программист',
    802: '802 программиста', 803: '803 программиста', 804: '804 программиста', 805: '805 программистов',
    806: '806 программистов', 807: '807 программистов', 808: '808 программистов', 809: '809 программистов',
    810: '810 программистов', 811: '811 программистов', 812: '812 программистов', 813: '813 программистов',
    814: '814 программистов', 815: '815 программистов', 816: '816 программистов', 817: '817 программистов',
    818: '818 программистов', 819: '819 программистов', 820: '820 программистов', 821: '821 программист',
    822: '822 программиста', 823: '823 программиста', 824: '824 программиста', 825: '825 программистов',
    826: '826 программистов', 827: '827 программистов', 828: '828 программистов', 829: '829 программистов',
    830: '830 программистов', 831: '831 программист', 832: '832 программиста', 833: '833 программиста',
    834: '834 программиста', 835: '835 программистов', 836: '836 программистов', 837: '837 программистов',
    838: '838 программистов', 839: '839 программистов', 840: '840 программистов', 841: '841 программист',
    842: '842 программиста', 843: '843 программиста', 844: '844 программиста', 845: '845 программистов',
    846: '846 программистов', 847: '847 программистов', 848: '848 программистов', 849: '849 программистов',
    850: '850 программистов', 851: '851 программист', 852: '852 программиста', 853: '853 программиста',
    854: '854 программиста', 855: '855 программистов', 856: '856 программистов', 857: '857 программистов',
    858: '858 программистов', 859: '859 программистов', 860: '860 программистов', 861: '861 программист',
    862: '862 программиста', 863: '863 программиста', 864: '864 программиста', 865: '865 программистов',
    866: '866 программистов', 867: '867 программистов', 868: '868 программистов', 869: '869 программистов',
    870: '870 программистов', 871: '871 программист', 872: '872 программиста', 873: '873 программиста',
    874: '874 программиста', 875: '875 программистов', 876: '876 программистов', 877: '877 программистов',
    878: '878 программистов', 879: '879 программистов', 880: '880 программистов', 881: '881 программист',
    882: '882 программиста', 883: '883 программиста', 884: '884 программиста', 885: '885 программистов',
    886: '886 программистов', 887: '887 программистов', 888: '888 программистов', 889: '889 программистов',
    890: '890 программистов', 891: '891 программист', 892: '892 программиста', 893: '893 программиста',
    894: '894 программиста', 895: '895 программистов', 896: '896 программистов', 897: '897 программистов',
    898: '898 программистов', 899: '899 программистов', 900: '900 программистов', 901: '901 программист',
    902: '902 программиста', 903: '903 программиста', 904: '904 программиста', 905: '905 программистов',
    906: '906 программистов', 907: '907 программистов', 908: '908 программистов', 909: '909 программистов',
    910: '910 программистов', 911: '911 программистов', 912: '912 программистов', 913: '913 программистов',
    914: '914 программистов', 915: '915 программистов', 916: '916 программистов', 917: '917 программистов',
    918: '918 программистов', 919: '919 программистов', 920: '920 программистов', 921: '921 программист',
    922: '922 программиста', 923: '923 программиста', 924: '924 программиста', 925: '925 программистов',
    926: '926 программистов', 927: '927 программистов', 928: '928 программистов', 929: '929 программистов',
    930: '930 программистов', 931: '931 программист', 932: '932 программиста', 933: '933 программиста',
    934: '934 программиста', 935: '935 программистов', 936: '936 программистов', 937: '937 программистов',
    938: '938 программистов', 939: '939 программистов', 940: '940 программистов', 941: '941 программист',
    942: '942 программиста', 943: '943 программиста', 944: '944 программиста', 945: '945 программистов',
    946: '946 программистов', 947: '947 программистов', 948: '948 программистов', 949: '949 программистов',
    950: '950 программистов', 951: '951 программист', 952: '952 программиста', 953: '953 программиста',
    954: '954 программиста', 955: '955 программистов', 956: '956 программистов', 957: '957 программистов',
    958: '958 программистов', 959: '959 программистов', 960: '960 программистов', 961: '961 программист',
    962: '962 программиста', 963: '963 программиста', 964: '964 программиста', 965: '965 программистов',
    966: '966 программистов', 967: '967 программистов', 968: '968 программистов', 969: '969 программистов',
    970: '970 программистов', 971: '971 программист', 972: '972 программиста', 973: '973 программиста',
    974: '974 программиста', 975: '975 программистов', 976: '976 программистов', 977: '977 программистов',
    978: '978 программистов', 979: '979 программистов', 980: '980 программистов', 981: '981 программист',
    982: '982 программиста', 983: '983 программиста', 984: '984 программиста', 985: '985 программистов',
    986: '986 программистов', 987: '987 программистов', 988: '988 программистов', 989: '989 программистов',
    990: '990 программистов', 991: '991 программист', 992: '992 программиста', 993: '993 программиста',
    994: '994 программиста', 995: '995 программистов', 996: '996 программистов', 997: '997 программистов',
    998: '998 программистов', 999: '999 программистов',

}
print(dct[int(input())])
```

#### Ну... или используйте алгоритм:

```
n = int(input())

if n % 10 == 1 and n % 100 != 11:
    end = ''
elif (n % 100 != 12 and n % 100 != 13 and n % 100 != 14) and (n % 10 == 2 or n % 10 == 3 or n % 10 == 4):
    end = 'а'
else:
    end = 'ов'
    
print('%s программист%s' % (n, end))
```